# Want to add a Collapse Button on the Table to expand it on the front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from "react";
import classes from "../CSS/DataUpload.module.css";
import * as XLSX from "xlsx";
import axios from "axios";
import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
import TableBody from "@mui/material/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@mui/material/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@mui/material/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@mui/material/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";

let initialSend = true;
const DataUpload = () => {
  const [sendData, setSendData] = useState([]);
  const [addData, setAddData] = useState(false);
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState(false);
  const [notification, setNotification] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    // console.log(sendData);
    // let payload = JSON.parse(sendData);
    // console.log("type of ", typeof payload);

    const excelData = async () => {
      // console.log(se)
      try {
        console.log(sendData);
        const url = "http://localhost:5000/users";
        const config = {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        };
        const response = await axios.post(url, sendData, config);
        const msg = response.data.msg;
        setNotification(msg);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    if (initialSend) {
      initialSend = false;
      return;
    } else {
      setDisplay(true);
      excelData();
    }
  }, [addData]);

  const onChange = (e) => {
    const [file] = e.target.files;
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (evt) => {
      const bstr = evt.target.result;
      const wb = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: "binary" });
      const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];
      const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];

      const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {
        header: [
          "no",
          "name",
          "vuln_type",
          "summary",
          "tech_details",
          "remediation",
          "req",
          "res",
          "cvss_score",
          "cvss_eq",
          "severity",
        ],
        blankrows: false,
      });
      data.shift();
      setSendData(data);
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  };

  const addDataHandler = () => {
    setAddData(true);
  };
  const removeNotification = () => {
    setDisplay(false);
  };
  // };
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {display && (
        <div
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "red",
            marginLeft: "100px",
            marginRight: "100px",
          }}
        >
          <p style={{ color: "white" }}>{notification}</p>
          <button
            style={{ float: "right", color: "white" }}
            onClick={removeNotification}
          >
            X
          </button>
        </div>
      )}

      <div className={classes.excelupload}>
        <p>Choose Excel File to Upload</p>
        <input type="file" id="input" onChange={onChange}></input>
      </div>
      <div style={{ margin: "50px" }}>
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
          <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} size="small" aria-label="a dense table">
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow sx={{ fontSize: 16 }}>
              <TableCell>No</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Name</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Vuln Type</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Summary</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Tech Details</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Remediation</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">req</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">res</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">cvss score</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">cvsseq</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">severity</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {sendData.map((row) => (
                <TableRow
                  key={row.no}
                  sx={{ "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 } }}
                >
                  <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                    {row.no}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{row.name}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{row.vuln_type}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{row.summary}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{row.tech_details}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{row.remediation}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{row.req}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{row.res}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{row.cvss_score}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{row.cvss_eq}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{row.severity}</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              ))}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
        </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default DataUpload;[enter image description here][1]
```

This the code for my front end. I want to add a collapse button to the request and response field. I have no idea about how to do it as I am a newbie in this field. I am making this project for our company. It fetches the data from MongoDB which is the back end. It would be really great if anyone can suggest how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? Toggle the visibility of the data ?

Comment: I just want to expand a specific column cell. Thanks in advance for the solution

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Here just I'm importing file from user and send it to DB via POST api using json format also im showing the data of file to frontend. the actual problem im facing is i want to add collapse buttons for for some cells of columns in order to wrap long request and response of an API.

Comment: You're generally expected to make an attempt before posting here. It sounds like you need to do a little training in JavaScript, React and Bootstrap so you have some foundational knowledge. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [Collapse](https://mui.com/zh/material-ui/react-table/#collapsible-table) component.

Just put your table into Collapse component, sth like ↓

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

return (
  <>
    <button onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
      {open ? "Collapse" : "Expand"}
    </button>
    <Collapse in={open}>
      <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      ....
      </TableContainer>
    </Collapse>
  </>
)
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-chihiro-1cgpo4?file=/demo.tsx) is the demo I've created, you can take a look.

**Update**

I think you need sth like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/77r47) example, horizontal collapse, am I right?

The example was not created by me though, I think it can give you some hints.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer but I just want to expand a specific column from the table for example the demo you have created i just want to expand the carbs cell.

Comment: @Nodenoder Hi, I've update my answer.